# Vim closes all folds on write

Tags: vim

I have the following *fold* option set in my vimrc:

```
set foldmethod=marker
```

Now when I enter `:w` or press `ZW` vim closes irregularly (meaning it doesn't happen every time) all existent folds, which are marked by `{{{...}}}` in the file. It happens with different filetypes as well.

It is really annoying and I would like to figure out how to prevent this behaviors.

Comment: have you config your vim by yourself? Do you understand each line in your vimrc file? Are you using those so-called "vim xyz distributions"?

Comment: There are two likely causes to this behavior: Either you have a plugin doing it for you or you have an autocommand in your configuration triggering at the event `BufWrite` or similar. What you can do is check [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) about how to debug your vimrc

Comment: @ statox Thanks, this helps a lot. My main problem what makes debugging difficult is that it only happens sometimes. Is there maybe a command what shows me all the auto commands which are fired off then I save a file?

Comment: [yes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-list)